# Unable to update my Edit Summary

Tags: support, edit-summary

While editing a question, the auto suggest in my browser showed an older/previous edit summary which was irrelevant. I selected it by mistake and clicked <kbd>Save</kbd>.

How can I update the edit summary? Or is this feature not available in Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

Go back and edit the same post within the grace period (5 minutes); change the edit summary and also make some other change (however small), and the original revision will silently be updated. (If you don't make any other change, the summary change will be lost.)